# (nested-radicals) tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Not so long ago I have noticed that there exists [nested-radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nested-radicals) tag. (It is still listed [among new tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?page=2&tab=new) so it cannot be very old. It was probably created in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533636/convergence-of-alternating-nested-radicals). At least it was the oldest question, which had that tag at this moment at the time I saw it for the first time.)

Will we keep the tag? (In that case, there are several old question where this tag can be reasonably added. I have already added this tag to several questions.)

Or would better solution be to make it synonym of [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series)? Or is it some better choice of a synonym?

Comment: Most nested radical problems are a subset of series problems, but I don't think I would want it to be a synonym for [tag:sequences-and-series].

Comment: I heard that in Africa there are factions of nested radicals, and the whole situation is on the brink of a continental war.

Comment: Similar situations are also happening for example on [tag:heat-equation] and [tag:wave-equation] tags. Those tags are having the characteristic that most OPs are not actively use them, making the meaning of existence of those type of tags tend to be impractical.